# Visual Studio Mac Installer fails to load

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to update my visual studio on my Mac to the latest version however my installer keeps failing. I tried deleting visual studio and then trying again but it won't work. Do I have to completely delete all visual studio files? How do I do that on a Mac (I'm usually a windows user and doing this for Xamarin usage)? Here is the error output:

> Initial task was failed
>   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   System.NullReferenceException
>
> at MacInstaller.Core.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem+<>c__DisplayClass53_0.b__0 (MacInstaller.Core.AvdInfo avd) [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/Installer/SoftwareItems/AndroidSDK/AndroidSoftwareItem.cs:190
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[TSource].ToList () [0x00017] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.Mac/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs:391
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.Mac/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:30
>   at MacInstaller.Core.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.CreateSystemImageSet (System.String platform, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] avds, MacInstaller.Core.AndroidSystemImageOptions asio, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] components) [0x00035] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/Installer/SoftwareItems/AndroidSDK/AndroidSoftwareItem.cs:190
>   at MacInstaller.Core.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.InitInstallationComponents () [0x0012f] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/Installer/SoftwareItems/AndroidSDK/AndroidSoftwareItem.cs:139
>   at MacInstaller.Core.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.InitInstaller () [0x00095] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/Installer/SoftwareItems/AndroidSDK/AndroidSoftwareItem.cs:112
>   at MacInstaller.Core.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.NeedsUpdate () [0x00024] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/Installer/SoftwareItems/AndroidSDK/AndroidSoftwareItem.cs:275
>   at MacInstaller.Core.TasksManager.DetectComponent (MacInstaller.Core.Installer.ISoftwareItem softwareItem) [0x0001f] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/TasksManager.cs:139
>   at MacInstaller.Core.TasksManager.DetectComponents () [0x00073] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/TasksManager.cs:118
>   at MacInstaller.Core.TasksManager+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__0 () [0x00074] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/TasksManager.cs:72
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.Mac/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2476
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.Mac/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at MacInstaller.Core.TasksManager.StartAsync () [0x00068] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/Core/TasksManager.cs:52

Comment: Uninstalling Visual Studio for Mac can be done by just dragging it to the Trash bin. The stack trace indicates something might be up with your Android SDK installation. Could you maybe try update that first?

Comment: TO completely uninstall VS for Mac, follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2019. And the installer logs are in: :/Users/<username>/Library/Logs/VisualStudioInstaller. Looks like it may be an issue with the Android SDK, so make sure to remove the Android SDK as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2019#uninstall-android-sdk-and-java-sdk